# Mocking Restful Service

Tags: java, rest, junit

I am trying to Junit test a client side code which calls some rest service. I am able to configure Grizzly etc but dont know how to mock the service. Could you please let me know how to do it.

Here is the client code

```
ClientResponse response =
    executor.invokeService(url,
                           authorizationToken, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
                           MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
InputStream is = response.getEntityInputStream();
JAXBContext context;
context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Release.class);
```

Could you please tell me the way to mock the above webservie call.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/mkotsur/restito to see whether that helps creating and setting up mocks for rest services.